# How to change Windows Server 2008 Login Screen

Tags: windows-server-2008

How do you change the settings on a windows server 2008 so that the login screen for remote desktop doesn't show any user names? I want to revert back to the old 2003 screen as this prompts for both a username and password. The new screen seems insecure to me as it gives anyone that might try and compromise the server valid login names.

Comment: Sure it is the server showing that, and not the CLIENT transmitting the last name to the server?

Just asking - same situation here.

Comment: when i rdp to the server on the login screen I see three users in the list and can click on any of them then enter a password. the only one that's not showing is Guest

Comment: Wouldn't this be best asked on ServerFault?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to configure this option using the security policy editor:

1. Log onto the server in question.
2. From the Start Menu, launch `secpol.msc`.
3. If you get a security warning, continue.
4. In the left pane, navigate to "Local Policies" and under that, "Security Options".
5. In the right pane, find "Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name" and enable it.
6. Log off.